# Viability of a Dyson Universe?

Tags: engineering, universe, dyson-spheres

So going beyond the idea of a Dyson Sphere where could a Dyson Universe be possible?

The Idea of a Dyson Universe is like a Dyson sphere with massive celestial engineering and construction in the spaces between stars and planets.

Instead of building a sphere around a star matter is imported from alternative universes to build the structures in the space between stars and turning the universe into a vast city.

Obviously such an object would need technology that breaks the laws of reality. Would there be a risk of the entire construction collapsing in on itself and turning the universe into a massive black hole?

Comment: If you put more matter in the interstellar space, you might have the universe contract. To me, this question is unclear. What do you mean by alternative universe, in your case?

Comment: @Magicsowon Well you couldn't fill out all the empty space between stars in the universe with matter because there isn't enough (at least of normal matter) so you need to use other universe's matter to make up the difference.

Comment: Conceptually interesting, but my query how are the alternative universes to build something between the stars? if there was any construction it would be those alternative universes & not between the stars in our universe. As for collapsing into a black hole that depends on where the mass is located, how much there is & in which universe(s).

Comment: Ah! That makes better sense. By importing matter from other universes. You should edit your question to add that detail. This will improve it & get rid of any confusion.

Comment: There is a novel by Asimov, called The Gods Themselves and he talks about connecting two parallel universes with different laws of physics. People extract energy, I think, from the other universe. You could make something similar.

Comment: Considering that the universe as a whole is closed, all energy emitted in it is also absorbed (sooner or later) in it. Therefore our universe as we know it is already a Dyson universe.

Comment: You may want to [edit] this to better describe what a Dyson Universe is. The description you provided doesn't match what I know about Dyson Spheres, so I'm not sure how one extends to the other.

Comment: I had to read the dyson-spheres tag to realize we weren't discussing a giant vacuum cleaner. I digress, I don't understand *how* one would try to enclose the universe within a wall-like construct because 1. doesn't our universe continually expand, and 2. what would be *outside* that wall?

Comment: @MSet I was thinking I was the only one... Those damn Dyson spheres, always wandering around in the Universe, vacuuming stars and stuff...

Comment: Mind... blown...

Comment: See the original Star Trek movie. Lots of good ideas in there for such a thing.

Comment: @MSet its not about building around the universe, more building around everything in it.

Comment: According to your description, a Dyson universe is "like a Dyson sphere" and later "massive celestial engineering and construction in the spaces between stars and planets."  That's two different things.  It is either like a Dyson sphere or it is composed of Dyson sphere-like constructions.  That's two separate and contradictory explanations.

Answer (score 2):

A big ball around the universe makes little sense.  There is really not that much energy to capture per square meter compared to surrounding a star, and the endless expansion just keeps making the situation worse.

But... we are going to throw all laws of physics our and make our own. What if the universe's surface area is extremely small?  Perhaps at the edge of the universe there is very little space, and all points begin to converge to a single point.  (like a 2d world actually being a planet so all points converge at the poles) If we just put our solar pannel there, now we are in business. All the extra energy of the universe captured by a 1 meter radius dish.

Comment: That was the topology cosmologists associated with a closed ("Big Crunch") universe, when that was still thought possible. But you drew the wrong conclusion; there wouldn't be anything special about one's celestial antipode; it would be a point in space like any other.

Comment: @Spencer I am just making stuff up to go with the absurdity of the question.    ANd in this cosmology there is only one pole, at maximum distance all space collapses to one point at the edge

Answer (score 0):

May make sense, beginning with a little amount of matter to build a single sphere, using the energy so synthesize more matter and go to another star but isn't that easy, if all the spheres are connected they may still want to orbit what can break the entire structure, then won't form a black hole immediately, otherwise the spheres can form smaller patches at size of planets, so the universe is safe, except by the thousands of shards and metal wandering around.